# Pass array of int from AngularJS to MVC C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I know this has been asked before. But when I'm trying those solutions they are not working.
So here I'm asking this question.

In my Angular File I'm using code:

```
$scope.BulkDelete = function (list) {
        var itemList = [];
        angular.forEach(list, function (value, key) {
            if (list[key].selected) {
                itemList.push(list[key].selected);
            }
        });


        //$scope.itemToDeleteId = null;                    

        $http({
            url: '/Admin/BulkDeleteMethod',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ itemsSelected: itemList }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).success(function (res) {
            //$scope.MyTblDataList = res;
            alert(res);
            //$scope.GetTblData($scope.TempName);
            $(".deleteModal").modal('hide');
        }).error(function (Data) {
            alert('Cannot Delete! Contact Support');
        });

    }
```

But I'm getting null in my C# Controller:-

```
public JsonResult BulkDeleteMethod(int[] itemsSelected)
    {
        using (SMContext dbContext = new SMContext())
        {
            try
            {
                if (itemsSelected == null)
                    return new JsonResult { Data = Constants.NoFileSelected, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsSelected.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var customer = dbContext.ClsMatObj.Find(itemsSelected[i]);
                        dbContext.ClsMatObj.Remove(customer);
                    }
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return new JsonResult { Data = Constants.DeleteSuccess, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new JsonResult { Data = Constants.NoFileSelected, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried 
`string[], List<int> and List<string>` but they are not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `headers:` option (the `contentType` needs to be `application/json` which is already set using the `contentType` option)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke this worked for me. Sometimes a silly mistake drives you crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Remove JSON.stringify from post method. Also remove the duplicate content-type

Comment: Yes, remove multiple content type